# How to find last space of a string using JavaScript and replace it with `&nbsp;`?

Tags: javascript

How to find last space of the para using JavaScript and replace it with `&nbsp;`?

`<p class="no-space">Web Development Reading List</p>`

(The space between the words "Reading" and "List" to be removed and want to have $nbsp; in place of that.

ie, `Reading&nbsp;List`

Comment: `string.replace( /([^\s])\s+([^\s]+)\s*$/, '$1&nbsp;$2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a replace with Regexp:

**Using ID**

```js
var noSpace = document.getElementById("noSpace");
noSpace.innerHTML = noSpace.innerHTML.replace(/ (?=[^ ]*$)/i, "&amp;nbsp;");
```

```html
<p class="no-space" id="noSpace">Web Development Reading List</p>
```

**Using class name:**

```js
var noSpace = document.getElementsByClassName("no-space");
for (var i = 0; i < noSpace.length; i++) {
    noSpace[i].innerHTML = noSpace[i].innerHTML.replace(/ (?=[^ ]*$)/i, "&amp;nbsp;");
}
```

```html
<p class="no-space">Web Development Reading List</p>
<p class="no-space">Web Development Reading List</p>
<p class="no-space">Web Development Reading List</p>
```

You can change `&amp;nbsp;` to `"&nbsp;"` if you need the character instead of the string.

Comment: Is it necessary to use id? I want to use it for multiple elements.

Comment: @bINO no you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("no-space")`. but be sure that it will return an array and for current example you have to use index `0`.

Comment: @bINO Updated with className

Answer (score 9):

Find your character by `lastIndexOf()` and use `subStr` to replace it through concatenation.

```
str = "Any string you want";
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
str = str.substr(0, lastIndex) + '&nbsp' + str.substr(lastIndex + 1);
```